# Ownerdraw CListCtrl checkboxes

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I want to add checkboxes to my CListCtrl-derived class, that has LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED-style for drawing them in any subitems. I can draw them simple inside DrawItem member function, but it look a little bit bad. How can I retreive the images of checkboxes, which are used for this control, if the LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES-style is set? It is important, because in each Windows version those checkboxes have its own unique look.

Is it possible?

Comment: I hardly believe that there is such _images_. The whole point in `LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` is to draw everything yourself as you like. Basically this is what Windows does in its default behavior. Anyways, why would you replicate standard Windows look? Make something nicer than in Windows, so that your control would look really distinguishable and appealing.

Comment: @Jovibor the problem is that there are many other places with standard-looking checkboxes in my app, for example - ctreectrl, property sheets, and if I add to list different checkboxes it will be looking mess

Comment: One of solutions that comes to mind is to `CreateWindow` with `BUTTON` class name and `BS_CHECKBOX` style, and *print* it in memory. Then `BitBlt` it.

Comment: @Jovibor Can you provide an example?

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-printwindow) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868840/taking-screenshot-client-area-using-printwindow-api).

Answer (score 0):

You call [`OpenThemeData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-openthemedata) to get the current theme's handle and then [`GetThemeBitmap()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-getthemebitmap) to get the images for the checkboxes.

Also have a look at the other `GetThemeXXXX()` functions to get the correct background
color, text color, font etc.

I also recommend you to play around with [ThemeExplorer](https://github.com/mity/theme-explorer), it should give you
a great overview how visual styles work. The best thing is, the tools actually uses
`OpenThemeData()` & co. to render a preview of the controls, so check out its [source code (main.cpp, Line 142+)](https://github.com/mity/theme-explorer/blob/master/src/main.c#L142) as well!